# jQuery simulate click on tab with code execution

Tags: jquery, ajax

The code below, when I click on a tab, I do a post and display the result in the tab. In some case, I'd like force the selected tab, but not only select the tab but select the tab + execute the code executed when I click on it.

In my exemple, I like select the second tab (jLikeToSet = 1) and execute the code :

```
$.post('/Home/e2', function (data) {
        $('#tabs-2').html(data);
});
```

jQuery :

```
    var $tabs = $("#tabs").tabs();
    var jLikeToSet = 1
    $("#tabs").bind('tabsselect', function (event, ui) {
        switch (ui.index) {
            case 0:
                $.post('/Home/e1', function (data) {
                    $('#tabs-1').html(data);
                });
                break;
            case 1:
                $.post('/Home/e2', function (data) {
                    $('#tabs-2').html(data);
                });
                break;
            case 2:
                $.post('/Home/e3', function (data) {
                    $('#tabs-3').html(data);
                });
                break;
        }
    });
```

HTML:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Screen 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Screen 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Screen 3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1"></div>
    <div id="tabs-2"></div>
    <div id="tabs-3"></div>
</div>
```

How can I do this ?

Thanks,

Update1 :
I tried to use this code :
`$('#tabs').tabsClick(1);` but no work, sample come from here  http://www.eduteka.org/ajax/tabs3/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To select programmatically a tab, call this function with `jLikeToSet` arg:

```
function selectTab(jLikeToSet){
    $("#tabs").tabs( "select" , jLikeToSet);
}
```

when this function is executed, it's as if you have selected manually, so what's inside `.bind('tabsselect'` will be executed.

Comment: This is much cleaner than the one I have posted. I was not aware of the select option. +1

Comment: with this code, I select the tab (index in jLikeToset) but nothing happen when I click on the tabs. I'd like, in some case, set a tab and execute the coede ... your solution is ok but I need to be able to execute code when I click on tab too.

Comment: FYI, I used "e1","e2" ... but can be "aaaa", "bbbb", "azerty"

Comment: As I said in the answer, the function to select a tab will lead to the same result as manual select; triggering the `tabsselect` event that you defined --> executing `$.post` for the selected tab. Try it.

Comment: As of jQuery UI 1.8 the "select" option has been deprecated, and removed in 1.9. Use the "active" instead as below:
`$("#tabs").tabs("option", "active", tabIndex);`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this script in the ready event and after the tabs are created:

```
$('#tabs-' + (jLikeToSet + 1) + ' a').click();
```

Comment: it's not only in tabs-2, but in the tab with the index store in jLikeToSet, in this case 1 but can be 0 or 2

Comment: @Kris: Solution posted by Manji is the better one. One small change you would need to do is to  use it this way: $("#tabs").tabs( "select" , jLikeToSet);

Answer (score 0):

I myself would change the jQuery to the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $tabs = $("#tabs").tabs();
    $('#tabs li a').click(function(){
        $.post('/Home/e'+location.hash.replace('#tabs-',''), function (data) {
            $(location.hash).html(data);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your users, it may be better to give your tabs names, so the user can go directly to them, such as https://www.example.com#documents

Then you can change your html to reflect that and make the "click" easier

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a id="documents_click" href="#documents">Documents</a></li>
        <li><a id="videos_click" href="#videos">Videos</a></li>
        <li><a id="profile_click" href="#profile">Profile</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="documents"></div>
    <div id="videos"></div>
    <div id="profile"></div>
</div>
```

So to choose the documents tab, all you need to do in jQuery is:

```
$('#documents_click').click();
```