# How i move into next tab using blur function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tabs

I want to create functionality when user use tab key for moving in to next tab. Every tab contains some text boxes. When user in last text box of tab 1 when it press the tab key, it will go into next text box of tab2. I am creating tab using plain HTML css and jQuery. I am not using tab functionality of jQuery UI but it is latest jquery. The below is my HTML. I am creating tab using ul and li. How I move into next li when my tab in first text box. The tabs contains like dropdown,checkboxes,texboxes. Note : i am not using tabindex due to some issue. i want to create using jquery)
for this i write a blur function.that blur function move the tabkey into next tab and focus on next tab.but the problem is how i am active the tabs and their content at the same time when we move into next tab

```
 <ul class='tabs'>
            <li><a href='#tab1'>Tab 1</a></li>
            <li><a href='#tab2'>Tab 2</a></li>
            <li><a href='#tab3'>Tab 3</a></li>
          </ul>
          <div id='tab1'>
            <ul class= "set2"> 
                <li>  test 1<asp:TextBox runat="server"  ID="test1" /></li>
                <li>  test 2<asp:TextBox runat="server" onblur=move() ID="test2" /></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div id='tab3'>
            <ul class= "set2"> 
                <li>  test 3<asp:TextBox runat="server"  ID="test3" /></li>
                <li>  test 4<asp:TextBox runat="server"  onblur=move() ID="test4" /></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div id='tab3'>
            <ul class= "set"> 
                <li>  test 5<asp:TextBox runat="server"  ID="test5" /></li>
                <li>  test 6<asp:TextBox runat="server" onblur=move() ID="test6" /></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
```

-script-

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
        $('ul.tabs').each(function(){
        // For each set of tabs, we want to keep track of
        // which tab is active and it's associated content
        var $active, $content, $links = $(this).find('a');

        // If the location.hash matches one of the links, use that as the active tab.
        // If no match is found, use the first link as the initial active tab.
        $active = $($links.filter('[href="'+location.hash+'"]')[0] || $links[0]);
        $active.addClass('active');
        $content = $($active.attr('href'));

        // Hide the remaining content
        $links.not($active).each(function () {
        $($(this).attr('href')).hide();
    });

        // Bind the click event handler
        $(this).on('click', 'a', function(e){
        // Make the old tab inactive.
        $active.removeClass('active');
        $content.hide();

        // Update the variables with the new link and content
        $active = $(this);
        $content = $($(this).attr('href'));

        // Make the tab active.
        $active.addClass('active');
        $content.show();

        // Prevent the anchor's default click action
        e.preventDefault();
    });
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simulate a click on a tab by:

```
$('#tab1').click();
```

There is a similar question here: [jQuery simulate click on tab with code execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5505553/jquery-simulate-click-on-tab-with-code-execution)

so for your case, the `onblur` event can be re-written as:

```
<li>  test 6<asp:TextBox runat="server" 
              onblur="funcation(){move(); $('#tab1').click(); }" 
              ID="test6" /></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use trigger("click")
Example: $("#tab2").trigger("click")